# how to run .show operation command using azure kusto for python

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, kql

I was wondering, if it is possible to run command : .show operation  details in python azure func using azure-kusto-data.

My code is working, but nothing is printed.

```
 client.execute(db, query) for row in response.primary_results[0]:
     print("value at 0 {}".format(row[0]))
     print("\n")
     print("Path:{}".format(row["Path"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run every valid query with this SDK, including this query. 
This code sample should work and you should get result for query:
`.show operation operation-id details`

Note that not all control commands persist their results and the `.show operation details command` can only be invoked after the operation completed successfully. Use the `.show operations operation-id` command) to check the State of the operation prior to invoking this command.

P.S empty results can be returned in various scenarios for example when exporting empty table.